# NSMutableOrderedSet addObject not ordered

Tags: objective-c, containers, nsmutableorderedset

I have an `NSMutableOrderedSet` which contains `NSDate` objects. Initially, here are the values:

```
2014-10-08 12:46:48 +0000
2014-10-08 12:46:42 +0000
```

After calling `addObject` with `2014-10-08 12:45:40 +0000`, I get the following output:

```
2014-10-08 12:46:42 +0000
2014-10-08 12:46:48 +0000
2014-10-08 12:45:40 +0000
```

Why aren't they ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `NSMutablOrderedSet` is not like a Java `TreeSet` which is kept sorted. Look at `addObject:` documentation:

> Appends a given object to the end of the mutable ordered set, if it is not already a member.

You should manually call

```
- (void)sortUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

or

```
- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

Comment: So basically it's an `NSMutableArray` which doesn't let me insert the same element twice?

Comment: It has all the common set operations: union, intersection, difference. They should be rather more efficient when working with other sorted sets (or sets in general)

Comment: Exactly. What order did you expect it to automatically assume? Ordered means that it will keep track of the position of items. If you change that position out will remember them. It doesn't mean "sorted" which is what I think you thought.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was sorted set, just like Java/C++ has.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to why they're not ordered, but you can sort them by date by doing that following:

```
NSArray *mySortedArray =[myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSComparisonResult result;

    NSDate *dateA = (NSDate*)obj1;
    NSDate *dateB = (NSDate*)obj2;

    result = [dateA compare:dateB];

    return result;
}];
```

Comment: Yeah, I just did that. I have been trying to wrap my head around `NSOrderedSet`in Objective-C, but I can't seem to get it. In Java or C++, when inserting something, it got sorted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically like NSMutable array but with no duplicate objects. 
The docs say addObjec: adds it to the end. 
You need to apply sorting using one of the following methods

– sortUsingDescriptors:

– sortUsingComparator:

– sortWithOptions:usingComparator:

– sortRange:options:usingComparator:

Think of it semantically the same as taking an NSMutableSet which has no order, creating an NSMutableArray from that and then not liking the order of the array. You need to tell it how to sort. The NSMutableOrderedSet doesnt have a DWIM (do what I mean) algorithm baked in, you tell it how.